# Converting int value to string value in list usage

Tags: c#

I need to convert the int value that says "1" to string value as below, but I don't know, I'm using new Microsoft Visual Studio so I don't know much about List<>, I would appreciate your help.

```
 List<string> cities = new List<string>();
cities.Add("Ankara");
cities.Add("Adana");


cities.Add("İstanbul");


cities.Add(1);    
cities.Add('A');
```

Comment: you mean... you need to type `"1"` instead of `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just to val.ToString(). (val in this case is whatever value that you will be adding in)

```
...
int value = 1
string str_val = value.ToString()
cities.Add(str_val)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to do it, as I said, I need to use List<> because ArrayList has been removed, but I don't know List<> very much. Thank you again.

Comment: No worries, happy to help.